# trying to sort discounted products in a Magento .phtml block, adding any function disables the block

Tags: php, magento, usort

I am trying to create a block which shows the 5 top selling products, 5 most viewed products and 5 largest discounted products on a Magento 1.7.0.2 site.

The block is defined as follows in local.xml:

```
<reference name="content">
   <block type="core/template" name="movies_block" template="catalog/product-block.phtml" before="-">
      <action method="setData"><name>category_id</name><value>5</value></action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

(you pass it a category id, the idea being it can be quickly reused throughout my theme for categories of my choosing)

I have written and tested code for displaying top sellers and most viewed, but I'm struggling with a way to efficiently sort the top 5 most discounted. I'm defining a discount as the % difference between 'price' and 'special_price'.

My code for this is as follows:

```
$visibility = array(
   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
);

$catNum = $this->getCategoryId(); // grab cat id from xml
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catNum);

// load products from $category
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                          ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                          ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
                          ->addCategoryFilter($category);

$saleProducts = array();        
$i=0;                                           
foreach($_productCollection as $product): 
   if($product->getSpecialPrice()): // if a product has a special price
      /* calculate discount as percentage and add it to $product array of each */
      $product['discount'] = $product->getSpecialPrice()/$product->getPrice()*100;
      $saleProducts[$i] = $product; // put discounted products into separate array
      $i++;
   endif;
endforeach;
```

This leaves an array $saleProducts, of products which have a 'special_price'. However, I want just the top 5 most discounted (highest value in $product['discount'] first).

I've been attempting to sort the array using:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
   return ($a['discount'] - $b['discount']);
}

usort($saleProducts, "cmp");
```

But as soon as I add anything to my code with 'function' in it, the whole block no longer displays... happens even if I just write:

```
function sortByDiscount($a, $b) {};
```

anywhere in the .phtml file, is Magento preventing me from creating a function? Anybody else tackled this particular problem? I have a feeling my way might be quite slow, especially since I used other product collections with filters earlier on in the same .phtml file, and this block needs to work with categories of up to 20,000 products.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: What PHP version do you have? Anonymous functions work only from PHP 5.3

Comment: PHP version 5.2.17, so that would be an issue, however attempting just adding 'function sortByDiscount($a, $b) {}' also disables the block... no error or anything, just the block stops displaying like magento is turning it's nose up!

edited my post to include this...

Comment: May be your display errors is switched of. Try to rewrite usort as suggested in answer below.

Comment: Try to move function to block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous functions are supported from PHP 5.3 on so you won't be able to use them.

As far as I know phtml file is included into it's block class so you can't write a new function in a phtml file. You will have to extend the block class or create a new helper class and then call

```
usort( $saleProducts, array('foo', 'bar'));
```

where foo is your class name and bar is the function name (and the comparator function should be static).

Comment: This sounds like the problem, however you've lost me with extending the block class or creating a new helper class... got any links to documentation where I can figure out how to do that in Magento?

Comment: Well you'll have to create a new module... See for example tutorials on this page http://alanstorm.com/category/magento. You could just write echo get_class( $this ); in your phtml file and you will get the name of your block class and then write a function in there to test if that's the problem (but this is not advisable for production as you won't be able to easily upgrade magento to a newer version...). A bit less messy solution but still not adwisable is that you copy the class file to the same location from app/core/somewhere to app/local/somewhere and add function there

Comment: It's a core/template block... get_class($this) gives 'Mage_Core_Block_Template', but I don't know where I would add my function... just kind of lost with the magento architecture

should I edit app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php?? 

(I understand this is core code I should override with module, just want to test)

Comment: Mage_Core_Block_Template means that the class is located in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php (just replace _ with / and you get the path).

Comment: cheers for your help, got it working now! get_class($this) is a pretty neat trick, will come in useful ;)

Comment: may I ask, why is overriding app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php with app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php not advisable?

Comment: Because you can't copy paste a newer version of magento over it without taking care what changes you have made and because those changes could break some extensions that you are using but mostly to keep core magento in tact. Other then that it's more a tradition of "how-you-should-extend-magento" so if the above issues don't bother you then you can do that without any side effects.

Comment: As for copying things to local instead of extending them - the code is no longer encapsulated in a single module and in your case the finctionality that you add to that class doesn't exactly belong there since that class is used as a base class for all blocks and should be extended so that the changes are visible only in a block where they are needed (again the encapsulation thing - easier to read the code and less error prone).

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Anonymous functions supported only from PHP 5.3.
Rewrite your usort method to be like:

```
usort($saleProducts, array($this, 'cmp'));
```

So, you will move your code to block and call its method.

Comment: See above comment, you're correct but this wasn't the issue, will update my original post with rewritten code...